# Uncaught ReferenceError: no is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick ((index):1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code

```js
var div = $("#divId").html("");
var messageId = 12;
var message = "not found";
div.append('<h1 class="text-danger" onclick="showMessage('+ messageId + ','+ message + ')">click here </h1>');

console.log( "ready!" );



function showMessage(id,msg) {
    alert('id :-'+id + ' msg:- '+msg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divId" >
         hi
</div>
```

how to solve this error I am stuck in here I am new in javascript so pl help

Comment: You're trying to add an  string without wrapping it with `\'`

Answer (score 1):

I would change the way your show message click event works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
AddHeaderTagToDom();
});

function AddHeaderTagToDom(){
var div = $("#divId");
var messageId = 12;
var message = "not found";
div.append('<h1 id="messageHeader" class="text-danger" data-message-id='+ messageId +' 
data-message-text ='+ message +'>click here </h1>');

BindShowMessage();
}

function BindShowMessage(){
$('#messageHeader').on('click',function(){
var id = $(this).data('message-id');
var text = $(this).data('message-text');

DoShowMessage(id,text);
});
}

function DoShowMessage(id,msg){
alert('id :-'+id + ' msg:- '+msg);
}
```

So basically when document loads append your h1 tag to a div element and register click event after you append the h1 tag. When h1 is clicked get the data properties for message id and text and call your showMessage method.

Comment: If you're using attribute for the string then you don't really need to wrap it with `'`  (`data-message-text ="'+ message +'"` could be `data-message-text ="+ message +"`), plus - by adding `id="messageHeader"` you allow adding multiple elements with the same ID to the DOM

Comment: The `id="messageHeader"` is used to simply demonstrate this example